# Why old usage (c++03) of auto does not compile under C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, c++03

I know that `auto` has a little usage before because it is the default for variables (opposite to static) - see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272481/what-was-auto-used-for-before)
Consider however valid C++03 code where, maybe for self-explanatory, this keyword was used:

```
auto int foo2 = 8;
```

It compiles under C++03, and does not compile under C++11. 
Is there any reason for not being back-compatible with C++03? 
What was the source of standard committee opinion that this keyword was not used? Are there any statistics of keyword usage?

BTW i tested with gcc - maybe this is a compiler bug?

Comment: this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k3ybftz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Have you ever seen code where the C++03 keyword was necessary? Have you even ever seen code where it has been used at all?

Comment: where on earth did you find code like that? I don't think anyone used auto. It's not even used in the code in the K&R book.

Comment: @PlasmaHH and @Tom - Fortunately not in production code. In my own code exercises from my early C++ years I was used this `auto` just to check if it works. And I was curious if this still compile. BTW, I believe it is worth to explore even rarely used features of the language - I used to know company when none knows how to use `goto`...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: In C++, that's probably a good thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was known that this breaks compatibility and is mentioned in Appendix C 2.3 Clause 7 of the standard. Given how useless auto has been and that it is really easy to fix the cost was deemed acceptable.

As for keyword statistics: Some companies with huge code-bases are on the committee, they probably know if it was acceptable, but I could not dig up any full statistics.

I did some standards archeology and the oldest paper that talks about `auto` seems to be N1478, which refers to a reflector message for the first discussing of auto (all later papers don't talk about breaking compatibility or reasoning).

Answer (score 12):

This was removed from C++11 because they have a new use for `auto`, and it would be confusing to allow `auto auto foo2 = 8;` to work. Nothing of significance is lost by removing this ancient and pointless declaration.

Comment: I have some skills in building translators and finding `conflicting specifiers` error for such case does not seem to me a very hard task. And why not allow `auto int a;`. It seems that Standard guys just find a reason to remove old, not used feature...

Comment: @PiotrNycz: "*It seems that Standard guys just find a reason to remove old, not used feature*" Oh no, they got rid of an unused feature. That's horrible... because... why?

Comment: @PiotrNycz I would be glad if they did that more often.

Comment: @PiotrNycz, parsing C++ is hard enough, making it more complicated just to support your exercises when you were learning C++ is not acceptable.

Comment: They are not being sarcastic.