# auto keyword strange behavior in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Theoretical question only - why i can't write such code:

```
auto auto foo = 0;
```

First auto keyword - storage class specifier (yeah, i know that it's useless and deprecated in C++11), second auto keyword - auto type-specifier.

So what's wrong?

And again - i don't really want to use this in real code.

Comment: Take a look at [dcl.spec.auto] in the C++11 standard. *5: A program that uses auto in a context not explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed.* There's no mention before that of the C++03 usage.

Comment: They really removed old meaning of `auto`. See my own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093717/why-old-usage-c03-of-auto-does-not-compile-under-c11. Maybe not related - but I believe this is perfectly valid: `static auto a =  7;`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `auto` storage class specifier is not "useless and deprecated in C++11," it has been removed entirely.  The `auto` keyword is no longer a storage class specifier and cannot be used as one.

In C++11, `auto` is a simple type specifier.

Comment: Oh, i see: Change: Remove auto as a storage class specifier

Comment: Yes, it is a breaking change, but it doesn't matter because the old use of `auto` (as a storage class specifier) was superfluous.

Comment: Also important:  it's a noisy breaking change, since old broken code won't compile under the new language rules.  Silent breaking changes are far worse, though C++11 has [some of those too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759232/stdvector-default-construction-c11-and-breaking-changes).

Answer (score 3):

From the [Stroustrup's FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#auto):

> ....The old meaning of auto ("this is a local variable") is now
>   illegal. Several committee members trawled through millions of lines
>   of code finding only a handful of uses -- and most of those were in
>   test suites or appeared to be bugs.

Which indicates there's much not code used using "auto" as storage specifier.