# Confusion about auto keyword in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, auto, storage-class-specifier

I'm confused by the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *foo()
{
   //Operation
}

int main ()
{
        auto int ret = foo();
}
```

I compiled the above code under GCC, but I got the following error:

```
error: two or more data types in declaration of 'ret'
         auto int ret = foo();
```

But, if I remove `int` type, like so:

```
auto ret = foo();
```

then it runs successfully.

`auto` is a **storage class** and `int` is a **data type**, then **why do I get the error "two or more data types" in the first case?**

Comment: Are you a time traveler from the past?

Comment: I'm not being rude but I've never seen anyone use `auto` as a storage-class specifier in the wild. I think that's why people accepted it could be re-purposed. Anyway now (C++11 on) it means `auto`matically deduce type and it's awesome.

Comment: Yep, they agreed to change it because they never found evidence of a single usage outside of compiler conformance test suites.

Comment: [auto keyword strange behavior in C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12183710/995714)

Comment: people who are voting this as off-topic are wrong. this is a legit question, but a duplicate

Comment: I blame old textbooks that are still being circulated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`auto` is not a storage class. It used to be, before C++11. But it was completely useless, so the keyword was re-purposed to allow automatic type inference. So when you say:

```
auto int ret = foo();
```

You are basically declaring the object to have 2 types (or possibly the same type twice), and that is an error. And when you say:

```
auto ret = foo();
```

The type of `ret` is determined by whatever the function `foo` returns, which is `int*` in this case.

Comment: Note that `auto` is still a storage class in C, even in the latest revision of the standard.  It's just as useless there as it is in C++, but the C committee tends to be _much_ more conservative about messing with the reserved words.

Answer (score 33):

> `auto` is a storage class

That used to be true before C++11 but not any more.

Starting from C++11, the meaning of the word has been changed. It is now used to automatically deduce types. See http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#auto.

> Why in first case I got an error "two or more data types"?

By using

```
auto int ret = foo();
```

you are trying to specify two types for `ret` -- one deduced and the other explicitly specified.

If you want to use an explicitly specified type, you can use:

```
int ret = *foo(); // Since foo() returns a pointer.
```

or

```
int* ret = foo();
```

or you can let the compiler deduce the type by using:

```
auto ret = foo();
```

Answer (score 10):

auto is NOT a storage class (not anymore since C++11) C++11 brings the keyword allowing the compiler to infer what is the type required for the variable you are declaring.

so basically doing **auto int myVar** is as invalid as **string double myVar2** or **bool long myVar3**... the variable can have only one data type defining it, and in your case the keyword auto does that...

how to get rid off the error:

Remove the **int** type and just use **auto**, doing so will let the compiler to ***AUTO***matically infer that type of the variable **ret** is exactly that  from what `foo()` returns :) just genial!

```
auto ret = foo();
```

from the [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

> For variables, specifies that the type of the variable that is being
>   declared will be automatically deduced from its initializer. For
>   functions, specifies that the return type is a trailing return type or
>   will be deduced from its return statements (since C++14). for non-type
>   template parameters, specifies that the type will be deduced from the
>   argument

Answer (score 4):

You wrote that:

> `auto` is a storage class

but this is no more true in [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (or later). The `auto` keyword has been [reused](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) for something completely different (some limited kind of [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference)). The former C++03 or C99 `auto` storage class is now (in C++11) always implicit and should *not* use the `auto` keyword.

<sup>(if you like type inference, C++11 is not doing it very well, but C++14 or C++17 have progressed on it; Ocaml has a much more powerful and interesting [Hindley-Milner type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) which is more "global"; that is why I wrote "some limited kind")</sup>

Comment: Why provide an answer when you are not sure *what* `auto` does in modern C++?

Comment: What make you think I am not sure? Actually, I am pretty sure of what I have written. And `auto` is doing some *very limited* type inference (much less powerful than what Ocaml has, for a counter example). Hence the *some* adjective

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I'm curious -- what, in a nutshell, is missing from `auto` that OCaml does?

Comment: Ocaml's (actually HM) type inference is computing the domain and target of functions globally, not just on one single expression.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think c++14 (but not c++11) has type inference for functions (and lambda expressions) as well, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: This reads like a "C++ is dumb, am I rite?" rant. The comparison to Ocaml provides no value in understanding what the C++ `auto` does or in answering the question.

Comment: @nwp The Ocaml comparison was edited in for clarification after someone complained about the expression "some limited type of type inference" and confused it for ignorance.

Comment: You said the automatic storage duration is now (in C++11) always implicit. But it always _was_ implicit, all the way back to C++98 and C89, so that hasn't changed.